# http://www.connect.facebook.com/widgets/fan.php repeating last "liker" twice?

Tags: facebook, facebook-widgets

I am using the likebox.

I am getting some strange results.

On Google chrome:
Says 7 likes, Shows 6 people, 7th person is the last "liker" repeated another time.

On Internet Explorer 
Says 6 likes, shows 4 people.

On Firefox
Says 6 likes, shows 4 people.

Live example:
[See the fan box on the right](http://jquery.webspirited.com/)

What is causing this?

How can I fix it?

What is causing this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of that box is generated by Facebook. You cannot change the way it works in any way. If it's displaying the wrong thing, then that's Facebook displaying the wrong thing.

Bottom line: You just have to live with it.